# How would one find the largest integer $n$ such that $n! < a^n$ for some integer $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial

How would one find the largest $n$ that satisfies

$$n!<a^n$$ where $a,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ for a given $a$ analytically?

Comment: What approaches have you taken?  Have you tried *anything*?  If so, show us your work.  Where did you encounter this question?

Comment: @amWhy No, I haven't. I don't know where to start because I've never come across a problem like this. I didn't encounter the question anywhere, I just tried proving that $n! > a^n$ as $n\to\infty$ and started wondering what the value of $n$ where the inequality flips would be for a given $a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approximation can be obtained from Stirling's formula. Taking the $n$th root of 
$$ a^n\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
we get $a\approx n/e$ or
$$ n\approx ea.$$
For example, with $a=1000$ we get the estimate $n\approx 2718$ when the correct value is $n=2713$.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially we have $$n!<n^n$$ while Stirling’s approximation gives $$ n!< (1+o(1))\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$ but for $n>2\pi$ you could say something like $$ n!<e\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n+1}.$$